# Inverse of a function involving trigonometry?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$g(x)=4-3\sin x$ is defined for the domain $x \in [\pi/2,A].$
The question is to find the largest value of $A$ for which $g$ has an inverse.
I was thinking to find the inverse of $g(x)$, and find the range of $g(x)$ since the range of the inverse=domain of the original function, but I didn't get the right answer.

Comment: It's better to do it generally: When does a function not have an inverse function?

Comment: @Arthur when it's one on one?

Comment: @JohnFire It needs to be onto too.

Comment: @JohnFire Here is [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations.

Comment: @Arbuja thank you.

Comment: @JaideepKhare what do you mean by onto too?

Comment: @JaideepKhare No, not in this case. We just fit the domain and codomain to make it onto. But yes, it _needs_ to be one-to-one. When does the sine function stop being one-to-one if we start at $\pi/2$?

Comment: Should be $(3/2) pi$ then @Arthur

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$

Comment: @Arthur thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

The inverse is intended to be a function. This means it cannot take on multiple values as the "vertical line test." What this means for $g(x)$ is that it cannot take on multiple values as a "horizontal line test" otherwise its inverse $g^{-1}(x)$ would fail the vertical line test. Working through this this will give you the interval.

Comment: Oh, so one x value can only have one y value, and only then we can have an inverse?

Comment: One x value can only have one y value is what makes it a function. One y value can only have one x value is what makes it have an inverse.

Comment: of fives Does that mean $x^2$ is not a function then?

Comment: @JohnFire No, it means that $x^2$ has no inverse function on the real line. It does have an inverse function if considered on $[0, \infty)$, however.

Comment: Ah, okay @Arthur thank you :)